# Oracle SQL query SELECT MINUS SELECT not working or too slow

Tags: sql, oracle

I do not understand why the following Oracle 10g SQL query is not working although each sub-query is working fine and fast on its own:

```
SELECT ref.EWO_ISSUE_ID, ref.EWO_REF_ID, ref.MSN_ID, ref.MSN, ref.HOV, ref.RANK, 
ref.EWO_WP_ID, ref.EWO_WP, ref.EPAC_TDU, ref.MOD, ref.MP, ref.EWO_REF_DESCRIPTION, 
ewo.EWO1, ewo.EWO2, ewo.EWO3, ref.TRS_ISSUE, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_1, 
ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_2, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_3,
ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_4, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_5, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_6,
ref.TRS_TECHDOM_INFO
FROM V_EWO_ACTUAL_REFERENCE ref
LEFT JOIN EWO_REFERENCE ewo
ON ref.EWO_REF_ID = ewo.EWO_REF_ID
WHERE ref.EWO_REF_ID IS NOT NULL
AND ref.TRS_TECHDOM_INFO IS NOT NULL

MINUS

SELECT EWO_ISSUE_ID, EWO_REF_ID, MSN_ID, MSN, HOV, RANK, EWO_WP_ID, EWO_WP,
EPAC_TDU, MOD, MP, EWO_REF_DESCRIPTION, EWO1, EWO2, EWO3, TRS_ISSUE,
TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_1, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_2, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_3,
TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_4, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_5, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_6,
TRS_TECHDOM_INFO
FROM EWO_REF_TRS_HISTORY;
```

I only get a time out error because it takes very long. Has anyone an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not solve your problem, but it will probably force a different execution plan:

```
with x as ( SELECT /*+ materialize */ ref.EWO_ISSUE_ID, ref.EWO_REF_ID, ref.MSN_ID, ref.MSN, ref.HOV, ref.RANK, 
                    ref.EWO_WP_ID, ref.EWO_WP, ref.EPAC_TDU, ref.MOD, ref.MP, ref.EWO_REF_DESCRIPTION, 
                    ewo.EWO1, ewo.EWO2, ewo.EWO3, ref.TRS_ISSUE, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_1, 
                    ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_2, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_3,
                    ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_4, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_5, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_6,
                    ref.TRS_TECHDOM_INFO
            FROM V_EWO_ACTUAL_REFERENCE ref
            LEFT JOIN EWO_REFERENCE ewo
            ON ref.EWO_REF_ID = ewo.EWO_REF_ID
            WHERE ref.EWO_REF_ID IS NOT NULL
            AND ref.TRS_TECHDOM_INFO IS NOT NULL ),
     y AS ( SELECT /*+ materialize */ EWO_ISSUE_ID, EWO_REF_ID, MSN_ID, MSN, HOV, RANK, EWO_WP_ID, EWO_WP,
                    EPAC_TDU, MOD, MP, EWO_REF_DESCRIPTION, EWO1, EWO2, EWO3, TRS_ISSUE,
                    TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_1, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_2, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_3,
                    TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_4, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_5, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_6,
                    TRS_TECHDOM_INFO
            FROM EWO_REF_TRS_HISTORY )
select *
from   x
minus
select *
from   y;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is new to me. I have tried it and it works fine. But i accept pravis answer because it is faster and more compact in its syntax.

Comment: @user2965923 . . . This looks like it would return the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT EXISTS or NOT IN and check something like this

```
SELECT ref.EWO_ISSUE_ID, ref.EWO_REF_ID, ref.MSN_ID, ref.MSN, ref.HOV, ref.RANK, 
  ref.EWO_WP_ID, ref.EWO_WP, ref.EPAC_TDU, ref.MOD, ref.MP, ref.EWO_REF_DESCRIPTION, 
  ewo.EWO1, ewo.EWO2, ewo.EWO3, ref.TRS_ISSUE, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_1, 
  ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_2, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_3,
  ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_4, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_5, ref.TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_6,
  ref.TRS_TECHDOM_INFO
FROM V_EWO_ACTUAL_REFERENCE ref
LEFT JOIN EWO_REFERENCE ewo
ON ref.EWO_REF_ID = ewo.EWO_REF_ID
WHERE ref.EWO_REF_ID IS NOT NULL
  AND ref.TRS_TECHDOM_INFO IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT EWO_ISSUE_ID, EWO_REF_ID, MSN_ID, MSN, HOV, RANK, EWO_WP_ID, EWO_WP,
    EPAC_TDU, MOD, MP, EWO_REF_DESCRIPTION, EWO1, EWO2, EWO3, TRS_ISSUE,
    TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_1, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_2, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_3,
    TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_4, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_5, TRS_UPDATE_ON_SHEET_6,
T   RS_TECHDOM_INFO FROM EWO_REF_TRS_HISTORY);
```

or try with `NOT IN`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You have forgot a "AND", but it works fine.

Comment: @user2965923 . . . Does this actually return what you want?  It doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: This is not an equivalent query (when you add the missing `AND`)

Comment: @Gordon and ypercube: why is this not correct/equivalent? It works correct for me and is logical for me.

Comment: The `not exists` portion is probably going to always return false because the there is no correlation in the inner query with the outer query.

Comment: @Gordon: i still do not understand what you mean. As far as understand the whole statement checks if the results of the outer query exist in the inner query and excludes them. And as i said: If the table referenced in the inner query is empty, i get the full result. If the table contains the same datasets, the result is empty. For me this is correct.

Comment: @user2965923  . . . Your understanding is incorrect.  `Not exists` checks whether the following subquery returns any rows or not.  What you are describing as "correct" in the comment is different from the intention of your original question.

Comment: @Gordon: now i understand! Thank you for explaining. I did not see the difference because i tested it with the full data only. Summing up and leaveing my confusion behind i totally agree with you: this solution does not aswer my original quesion!

Answer (score 0):

At first i was thinking that the first answer is correct, but it is not! The second works fine. I tried it like this and it seems to work, but it is much slower than Jens's answer.

```
SELECT columns
FROM V_EWO_ACTUAL_REFERENCE ref
LEFT JOIN EWO_REFERENCE ewo
ON ref.EWO_REF_ID = ewo.EWO_REF_ID
WHERE ...
AND ...
AND (...) NOT IN (SELECT columns FROM EWO_REF_TRS_HISTORY);
```

But finally i am still confused about the MINUS in the query of my question making so much trouble.